# Display Float In UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am having an issue with using a float in a UILabel.

```
float doubleNum;

floatNum = 10 / 20;

cashLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];
```

If I use "floatNum = 10 / 10;" it correctly returns "1.000000000", however, if I put in "floatNum = 10 / 20" it returns "0.0000000". I have tried about everything I know and it does not work. I know it's a dumb mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Happy Holidays. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast one of the integer's to a float.

Try replacing the divisional line with:

```
float floatNum = (float) 10 / 20;
```

and you should get the correct answer.

Or if possible just use floats in your division:

```
float floatNum = 10.0f / 20.0f;
```

should also work

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are assigning floatNum the result of dividing one INTEGER by another. The result of 10 / 20 is indeed 0 and as a float, it appears as 0.0000000. In order to obtain a proper result, you need to either use a cast type to turn it into a float or add a .0 to one of the numbers. In division, if one of the numbers is a float (which is easily done by just adding a .0 to one of them), the result will be a float as well.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, C performs "integer division" (basically, division without the remainder -- 10/3 is 3R1, so it yields **3**).
When you type `floatNum = 10/20`, it does `10/20 = 0` (remainder 10).
To fix this, you have to **tell** the program that you're giving it floating point numbers. Try using:
`floatNum = 10.0 / 20`,
`floatNum = 10 / 20.0`, or
`floatNum = float (10 / 20)`.
All of those should work.

Comment: Thank you, so much! I didn't even think of that. I figured it'd do that automatically. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

try `floatNum = 10.0f/20.0f` (i.e. make sure the calculation is being done with floats rather than ints)

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example to understand how floats work:

```
float a = 1/120;
float b = 1.0/120;
float c = 1.0/120.0;
float d = 1.0f/120.0f;

NSLog(@"Value of A:%f B:%f C:%f D:%f",a,b,c,d);

Output: Value of A:0.000000 B:0.008333 C:0.008333 D:0.008333
```

For float variable a : int / int yields integer which you are assigning to float and printing it so 0.0000000

For float variable b: float / int yields float, assigning to float and printing it  0.008333

For float variable c: float / float yields float, so 0.008333

Last one is more precise float. Previous ones are of type double: all floating point values are stored as double data types unless the value is followed by an 'f' to specifically specify a float rather than as a double.

Change your code to:

```
float floatNum;

floatNum = 10.0f / 20.0f;

cashLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];
```